# StackOverflow exception, Infinite loop or actual stack overflow

Tags: stack-overflow, infinite-loop

If I enter this in with the arguments 0,0,0,15 I get a stack overflow exception.. What could be the cause of this? Is is an infinite recursion or is it actually too much for the stack? The size of lighting 3D array is 16 * 16 * 128

```
private void updateLight(int x, int y, int z, byte lightValue) {
    if (lightValue == 1 || lighting[x][z][y] != -1 || voxels[x][z][y] != 0) {
        return;
    }

    lighting[x][z][y] = lightValue;

    if (x - 1 >= 0) {
        updateLight(x - 1, y, z, --lightValue);
    }
    if (x + 1 < lighting.length) {
        updateLight(x + 1, y, z, --lightValue);
    }
    if (z - 1 >= 0) {
        updateLight(x, y, z - 1, --lightValue);
    }
    if (z + 1 < lighting[0].length) {
        updateLight(x, y, z + 1, --lightValue);
    }
    if (y - 1 >= 0) {
        updateLight(x, y - 1, z, --lightValue);
    }
    if (y + 1 < lighting[0][0].length) {
        updateLight(x, y + 1, z, --lightValue);
    }

}
```

Comment: it's not loop, but recursion

Comment: @Alex Whoops thats what I meant.

Comment: to get stackoverflow it shouldn't be infinite, just more then you stack have.

Comment: @Alex I know that. But I kinda doubt that the stack would overflow for 16 * 16 * 128 operations when most are filtered right away. Thats why I am asking is there infinite recursion here.

Comment: you can check in debugger

Comment: to avoid stackoverflow you can convert to to loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the first call will hit the second condition, and call `updateLight(x + 1, y, z, --lightValue);` which is `updateLight(1, 0, 0, 14);`. That recursive call will then hit the first condition, and call `updateLight(x - 1, y, z, --lightValue);` which is `updateLight(0, 0, 0, 13);`. Since none of the conditions depend on lightValue, this is identical to the first call as far as flow control. So it's just going to bounce back and forth between those two recursive calls until the stack overflows.

You should be able to verify this easily in a debugger.